# Angular send http request while switching routes

Tags: angular

After a user uploads an image, I need to switch route to another component to show the response data. How can I get the response data of previous HTTP request in the new component?

Comment: show your code. so that we can help you.

Comment: Do you want to show the image upload response data in the component you are redirecting to?

Comment: Request again in your new component or save that somewhere in client side

Comment: @Saeed.At This is a good idea, thank you for your reply.

Comment: good luck ...:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Input` and `Ouput` directives you can pass data from one component to another.

Check this. This should help.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interactionanother

Implement this and then if you face issue people are here to help you.

Comment: I need to switch the route. It is not only pass the data between component.

Comment: Yes, that is achievable using Routing.